# C++ pointer array porting to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I have the following scenario in C++ code that I'm porting to Delphi.

Struct defined as follows:

```
typedef struct tagMyType
{
    LPVOID  pData;              // allocated by the client
} MyType, FAR* LPMyType;
```

I am passing this structure to an external DLL which fills data in it.
According to the documentation I have it states the following:

> pData will point to a packed list of null terminated strings

I declared the record in Delphi as follows:

```
TMyType = record
  pData: POINTER;
end;
PMyType = ^TMyType;
```

Memory allocation and DLL call is successful, the pData gets filled.

The C++ code then treats this field as an array, thing that I cannot do in Delphi as per the pData is declared.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    printf( "%d", ((ULONG*)stEnum.pData)[i] );
```

I know C++ can handle Pointers as arrays, I would like to know how can I do the same in Delphi painlessly.

Comment: "*thing that I cannot do in Delphi*" - yes, you can, if you typecast `pData` to `PULong` and then use [Pointer Math](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)) to access its values using array syntax, just like the C++ code is doing

Comment: "I know C++ can handle Pointers as arrays,"  pointers are not arrays in C or C++ - arrays will often decay to pointers, but they are not pointers. It looks to me as if both your C++ and Delphi structures are wrong in that they don't actually allocate any memory for `pData`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the Pointer Math I was not aware it existed, now my code works. WriteLn(Format('%d. [PULong(stEnum.pData)[i]]));

Comment: @NeilButterworth pData is filled by an external DLL call, I didn't put this in the question as for me was irrelevant. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Is it possible to change the record structure? If you use a record like this : `TMyRec = packed record counter : cardinal; strings : array [0..0] of pchar; end;` then you can know the count of lines, access them in an array like form and you avoid issues caused by unicode characters.

Comment: @User007 since it points to a pointer IMO you cannot declare like that. By the way it's enough to cast it and access it as a normal Delphi type, I found it very useful.